# Appending list to character

Tags: prolog

I'm attempting to append the Head of a list to an atom, recursively, however prolog keeps returning false and I'm unable to determine why.

My original code:

```
listpicket(K, [H1|T1], L) :-
    append([K], [H1], L),
    listpicket(K, T1, L).
```

Run like:

```
?- listpicket(k, [a,b,c], L).
```

Expected output:

```
[k, a, k, b, k, c].
```

Actual output:

```
false.
```

Suspecting the `false` is coming from the last recursive iteration, where there is no tail (`T1`, here), I tried handing that case like so:

```
listpicket(K, [H1|T1], L) :-
    (
        not(is_list(T1)),
        [K|T1]
    );
    append([K], [H1], L),
    listpicket(K, T1, L).
```

But I also get `false` as the result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `append` means add at the end not in the begining .

Comment: @LuaiGhunim I'm aware, that's why I'm appending the head to my atom. so that I get `[k, a, k, b, ...]`. So trying to append the Head of the list to my variable `K` into a new list `L`, and repeat recursively by passing the tail of the list into the recursive call (getting the head of that new list, etc).

Comment: you get false because you have no base case and also the second time you call append it will fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fail comes because when second time you call the `append/3` you must have an unistantiated variable but L is at that time isntantiated.

`append/3` says give me two lists and one variable/un-instantiated and i will return concatenated lists.

You can adjust your code like this:

`

```
listpicket(K, [H1|T1], [NewL|L]) :-
   append([K], [H1], NewL),
   listpicket(K, T1, L).`
```

and the base-case:

```
listpicket(_,[],[]).
```

This code will work but still you will not get expected result because you are created lists in a list. Everytime `append/3` returns a list and we add it as the head of the list.

Well, i will work this out like this:

```
listpicket(_,[],[]).
listpicket(K,[H|T],[K,H|L]):-
  listpicket(K,T,L).
```

Comment: I did have a base case, actually, like `listpicket(K, [], K).`, but that wouldn't have worked like you have written it. I didn't even think of "appending" within the parameters list! I have quite a bit of prolog to study... :/

Comment: I need 15 rep to upvote you, otherwise I would. Sorry!

Comment: lol np , Prolog is fun :) I would like to say that in beginning you should use graphical tracer. go to prolog and then type `guitracer.` then `trace` then execute your query , you can follow step by step

Comment: Thanks! I was using https://swish.swi-prolog.org/ a bit and their debugger, but am used to languages where you can see variable contents at each step. Prolog is a different way of thinking - I'll give the swi-prolog installed version's guitracer a try.

Comment: oh yes, `guitracer` is much better! Thanks for the tip!